# AWS Certificate Manager not working in godaddy domain

Tags: amazon-web-services

It is a kind of experiment to know how aws domain things working

AWS Certificate Manager seems fine but not showing https,
Please note I haven't changed name servers in godaddy or I haven't touched Route53 in aws

See steps

1. I have purchased a domain from Godaddy - example.com
2. In aws s3 , I have created a static site - bucket name is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
   s3 bucket site url is http://www.example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
3. I have created a CNAME in godaddy -
   [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) > http://www.example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
4. And I use forwarding option in godaddy
   example.com redirect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

So far its working fine
When I enter and hit example.com in browser it open [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Now I have created single ACM certificate in aws for example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and put it in godaddy as CNAME for verification

and Showing status is Issued in aws under ACM

but when Open site ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) it is not showing in **HTTPS** instead of http

**Why https not working ?**

Comment: Just having an SSL certificate issued does not make it automatically work with your domain. You also have to attach the SSL certificate generated by AWS ACM to something capable of serving that certificate. ACM certificates can only be used by AWS CloudFront, API Gateway, and AWS Load Balancers.

Comment: A simple choice would be CloudFront

Comment: Ohh Okay , I should attach ssl to CloudFront and put CloudFront url in godaddy (step 3 in above question) @erik258

Comment: Yeah you'll have to CNAME to the cloudfront endpoint.  Note that's a DNS setting and DNS  does not take URLs.  Just the hostname.

Comment: Will it work just with cloudfront url and  WITHOUT touch Route 53 @erik258

Comment: Yeah you don't need route53.  The one  big thing Route 53 will do for you is simplify ACM cert renewals.  Using Route 53 will also allow you to use ALIAS records instead of CNAME, but that doesn't make a big difference.

Comment: I think you can answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77800427/taking-too-much-time-to-reflect-aws-route53-new-record-aws-sdk @erik258

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cloudfront for your use case.

- Create cloudfront distribution
- Select your s3 bucket in Origin domain
- give the name in name field
- In default cache behaviour.
- choose Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Viewer protocol policy
- Add your domain in Alternate domain name field.
- choose SSL certificate which you created in ACM in Custom SSL
  certificate field.
- mention index.html filename in Default root object.
- Add your cloudfront URL as a value of your domain CNAME record.

Comment: Will it work just with cloudfront url and  WITHOUT touch Route 53 ?

Comment: you need to create one CNAME record for your domain with cloudfront URL value

`record name: www.exmple.com (your domain)`
`record type: CNAME`
`record value: your cloudfront URL`