# Taking too much time to reflect aws Route53 new record - AWS SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating new record in aws route53 from **nodejs AWS-SDK**

Everything is fine but taking too much time to reflect ( I check newly added sub domain on browser  ) new record which I added in Route53

Note : If I am doing manually its reflecting very quickly

```
    let changeResourceRecordSetsParams = {
        ChangeBatch: {
            Changes: [
                {
                    Action: "CREATE",
                    ResourceRecordSet: {
                        Name: "example.mydomain.com",
                        //TTL: 60,
                        Type: "A",
                        AliasTarget: {
                            DNSName: "s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
                            EvaluateTargetHealth: false,
                            HostedZoneId: ''
                        },

                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        HostedZoneId: ""
    }; 
  return await route53.changeResourceRecordSets(changeResourceRecordSetsParams).promise();
```

Note: I cannot add TTL time along with this function, if I am adding **TTL: 60** it will not work error is

"Invalid request: Expected exactly one of [AliasTarget, all of [TTL, and ResourceRecords], or TrafficPolicyInstanceId], but found more than one in Change with [Action=CREATE, Name=atwo.hunterrock.com, Type=A, SetIdentifier=null] "

**Why its taking too much time to reflect? but its reflecting quickly if I am doing manually ?**

Comment: What do you mean by "to reflect new record"? How are you verifying the record -- are you simply waiting for something to appear in the management console, or are you attempting to resolve a DNS name to an IP address (and how are you doing that)?

Comment: I  check domain ( example.com )  available on browser   @JohnRotenstein